# OCR: accurately recognize similar characters (diacritics)

Tags: algorithm, opencv, machine-learning, ocr, theory

Given:

- black and white bitmap images of characters from a scanned book in a European language (in this case, Polish)
- each character is about 20 pixels high, 4-18 pixels wide
- limited learning sample
- unlimited processing time
- unlimited memory

Task:

- make a computer recognize characters of a given font with best accuracy in regards to **very similar characters** (like Polish letters with diacritics: `l` vs `ł`, `ż` vs `ź`)?

What approach would you recommend for this to a novice in computer vision and AI? Should I use neural networks? CNN? Some algorithm from OpenCV? Perform some math on the matrices?

Sample data (this is not a complete learning sample, of course, but it shows the challenges):

Letters `ż` and `ź`:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _      _ _ _ _ % % _ _
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _      _ _ _ % % % _ _
 _ _ % % % _ _      _ _ _ % % % _ _
 _ _ % % % _ _      _ _ _ % % _ _ _
 _ _ % % _ _ _      _ _ _ % _ _ _ _
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _      _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
 % % % % % % _      _ % % % % % % _
 % % % % % % %      % % % _ % % % _
 _ _ _ % % % _      _ _ _ _ % % _ _
 _ _ % % % _ _      _ _ _ % % % _ _
 _ _ % % _ _ _      _ _ _ % % _ _ _
 _ % % % _ _ _      _ _ % % _ _ _ _
 % % % _ _ % %      _ % % % _ _ _ %
 % % % % % % %      _ % % % % % % %
 % % % % % % %      _ _ _ _ _ % % _
```

Three letters `l`:

```
 _ % % %      _ % % % _      _ _ % _ _
 % % % %      % % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ _ % % _
 _ % % _      _ _ % % _      _ _ % % _
 _ % % _      _ _ % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ _ % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ _ % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ _ % % _      _ _ % % _
 _ % % %      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 % % % %      % % % % %      % % % % %
 % % % %      _ % % % _      % % % % %
```

Three letters `ł`:

```
 _ _ % _      _ % % _ _      _ _ % % _
 % % % _      % % % % _      _ % % % _
 % % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 % % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % %      _ _ % % %
 _ % % %      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % %      _ % % % _      % % % % _
 % % % _      % % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      _ _ % % _      _ _ % % _
 _ % % _      _ % % % _      _ % % % _
 _ % % _      % % % % %      % % % % %
 % % % %      % % % % _      % % % % _
```

As you can see, perceivable differences can be only in a couple of pixels. And the challenge, I guess, is to teach a computer to "notice" those important pixels more than others.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: How much training data do you have? In any case I would start with a kNN classifier to have a baseline, that will give you an idea how hard the problem is. It can usually be implemented in a few lines of code.

Comment: @SaiBot, around 10000 letters. But some letters are more frequent than the others and this is represented in my training data (for example, there are many variants of letters `a`, `e`, `c`, `u`, `n`, etc., but `ź` is very rare). Thanks for the advice!